# Running a SPSS-Syntax from excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, spss

I'm trying to run a SPSS-Syntax-command (as an example: "freq v1.") from an Excel-File using vba.
This used to work, but somehow not anymore. I have no idea why, I didn't change anything.
Here is the code:

```
text="freq v1."
Set objSpssApp = GetObject(, "Spss.Application")
Set objOutputDoc = objSpssApp.NewOutputDoc
objSpssApp.ExecuteCommands text, True
```

Has anyone an idea why this is not working anymore?

Thx a lot!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: do you have the SPSS Type Library referenced ? If you re-installed MS Office, or changed computers, you might need to set it up again: In the VBA Editor window, Tools Menu, References, lookup "SPSS..." and tick it

Comment: thx, but yes, SPSS Type Library is ticked.I get an error-message "License information for this component not found. You don't have an appropriate license to use this functionality in the design environment (Error 429)".

Comment: If you press "Debug", which line does it point to ? Do you have licenced SPSS, or trial version installed ?

Comment: It´s not pointing to a specific line; it seems that it won´t even start. When I am trying to start the code out of the vba-Editor, this error-message is shown: "Error 429; ActiveX component can't create object". (The error-message in my comment above appears, when I run the code out of Excel (using a button to start it).

Comment: I have a licensed Version installed.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC Spss.Application became Spss.Application16 some years ago.  But you would require an SPSS license to use this.